# Sorting a dictionary list in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Please am following a tutorial on http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/06/django-blog-project-6-creating-standard/.The code creates tags and list them by their count. Below is the code am having problems with.

```
def create_tag_data(posts):
tag_data = []
count = {}
for post in posts:
    tags = re.split(" ", post.tags)
    for tag in tags:
        if tag not in count:
            count[tag] = 1
        else:
            count[tag] += 1
for tag, count in sorted(count.iteritems(), key=lambda(k, v): (v, k), reverse=True):
    tag_data.append({'tag': tag,
                     'count': count,})
return tag_data
```

I don't understand this line

```
  for tag, count in sorted(count.iteritems(), key=lambda(k, v): (v, k),reverse=True):
```

it tells me unpacking is not supported in python 3. Am using python 3. Please how do i write that particular line in python 3.

Comment: What is the full traceback you're getting from that?

Comment: you probably want to have a different variable for `count` in the first part of  your `for`, since that is for your dictionary.   So, maybe `for tag, tag_count in ... `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you cannot use the following in *Python 3.x* - `lambda(k, v)` - the *tuple parameter unpacking* , which automatically unpacks a tuple/list/sequence of two items into `k` and `v` .

Also , there is no `dict.iteritems()` in *Python 3.x* , you need to use `.items()` , which returns a view in Python 3.x

You can instead use -

```
 for tag, count in sorted(count.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True):
```

---

This was introduced in Python 3.0  as part of [PEP 3113 - Removal of Tuple Parameter Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

And from Python 3.x onwards `dict.items()` returns views instead of `list` , and hence the `dict.iteritems()` (and `dict.viewkeys()` and `dict.viewvalues()`) were removed as part of [PEP 3106 - Revamping dict.keys(), .values() and .items()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/)

Answer (score 4):

You need `.items` and you can use `itemgetter` which will work in python2 or 3 and is more efficient than a lambda, taking the value first with `(1, 0)` to use the value as the first key to sort with:

```
from operator import itemgetter


count = {1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 6}
for tag, count in sorted(count.items(), key=itemgetter(1,0), reverse=True):
    print(tag, count)
```

Output:

```
3 6
2 4
1 3
```